# Unable to assign the lookup value of the newly created record

Tags: apex

I am unable to assign the lookup value of the newly created record to a lookup value field. The record is inserted properly and I am able to retrieve the id, but I cannot assign it for some reason. Please note that I am using a button. Thanks in advance.

```
global class Otg_Interaction_Buttons {

  global Otg_Interaction_Buttons() { }

    webservice static void createReqFromInt(Id currentRecordId){       

    Set<Id> contId = new Set<Id>();                           
    List<Request__c> reqToInsert = new List<Request__c>();

    List<Interaction__c> intLst = [select Id,name,Contact__c from Interaction__c where Id = :currentRecordId];    

    for(Interaction__c i : intLst) {
         if(i.Contact__c != null){                       
            contId.Add(i.Contact__c);
         }                        

    List<Contact> contLst = [select Id,name,FirstName,LastName from Contact where Id = :contId];

         Request__c req = new Request__c();
         req.Contact__c = contLst[0].Id;                                               
         reqToInsert.add(req);

         if(reqToInsert.size()>0){
            insert reqToInsert;                             
         }  
         System.debug('The Req inserted equal:'+ reqToInsert.Size());

      i.Request__c = req.Id; //This is not getting assigned
      }         
   }                                                                                                  
}
```

Comment: How do you knw its not getting assigned? you are not doing any dml on `Interaction__c ` list

Comment: I thought I didn't need anything other than i.Request__c = req.Id since interaction__c is the current object record. The button is on interaction and it creates a request, but I want to update the interaction with the request id. Any other guidance you could provide? My apologies I am a little lost on this one.

Comment: As I can see its a webservice call(Not trigger context), and you are querring interaction records. After you have assigned the value you have update the `intLst`

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I got it to work. I'll post my solution in a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED:

global class Otg_Interaction_Buttons {

```
  global Otg_Interaction_Buttons() { }

    webservice static void createReqFromInt(Id currentRecordId){       

    Set<Id> contId = new Set<Id>();                           
    List<Request__c> reqToInsert = new List<Request__c>();
    Id reqId;

    List<Interaction__c> intLst = [select Id,name,Contact__c from Interaction__c where Id = :currentRecordId];    

    for(Interaction__c i : intLst) {
         if(i.Contact__c != null){                       
            contId.Add(i.Contact__c);
         } 
    }              

    List<Contact> contLst = [select Id,name,FirstName,LastName from Contact where Id = :contId];

         Request__c req = new Request__c();
         req.Contact__c = contLst[0].Id;                                               
         reqToInsert.add(req);

         if(reqToInsert.size()>0){
            insert reqToInsert;                             
         }  
         System.debug('The Req inserted equal:'+ reqToInsert.Size());

         reqId = req.Id;

    for(Interaction__c i : intLst) {
         if(i.Contact__c != null){                       
            i.Request__c = reqId;
         }
      update intLst;
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: Yes the code works, but its not bulkified, Thus its prone to errors. Can you remove  SOQL and DML from for loop? SF being a multitenant cloud platform, there are limits on it. You should try to bulkify your code.

Comment: `if(reqToInsert.size()>0)` is not required